# Print Numbers from 1 to 1000 using oops concept

Tags: c#, oop

How to print numbers from 1 to 1000 using oops concepts (i.e) without using loops, array and recursion

Comment: like this? ```Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);```

Comment: You can write 1000 `WriteLine` calls. Any other way is using loops, whether directly or beyond the hoods.

Comment: Can you tell you teacher that the whole community would be glad to know if (s)he was able to do it and if yes, how?

Answer (score 6):

Since you mentioned the OOP concepts, one of which is encapsulation. You don't care about the implementation details when the method gets the job done.

Almost all linq extension methods use loops (Actually differed Iterators) in their implementation, it is easy not to realize that because it is a details encapsulated in the implementation.

To answer your question, **the only way to do that without a loop is to write the WriteLine call 1000 times.**

In OOP, you create a class to encapsulate the logic and then use it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        (new RangePrinter).PrintRange(1, 1001);
    }
}
```

No loops right ? Actually the loop is encapsulated in the implementation.

```
class RangePrinter
{
   /* Injecting the Write target is skipped for simplicity */

   public void PrintRange(int lowerBound, int upperBound)
   {
      for(int i = lowerBound; i < upperBound; i++)
      {
         Console.WriteLine(i);
      }
   }
}
```

The same applies when you use Enumerable (aka Linq extension methods):

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).ToList().ForEach(x=> { Console.WriteLine(x); });
```

Here how the .NET Framework team implements the Range Internal Method:

```
static IEnumerable<int> RangeIterator(int start, int count) {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) yield return start + i;
        }
```

Conclusion, when you need to do repetitive work then you need a loop. Any C# API that iterates over a collection (Linq's Where, Select, etc..) uses a loop. Loops are not bad unless the are not needed or they are nested when there is alternative approaches.

---

**Just for fun**, if this is meant to be a puzzle (forget the OOP requirement part), then you can do this:

```
string oneToThousand = @"1\r\n2\r\n3\r\n4\r\n5\r\n6\r\n7\r\n8\r\n9\r\n10\r\n11\r\n12\r\n13\r\n14\r\n15\r\n16\r\n17\r\n18\r\n19\r\n20\r\n" +
                        "21\r\n22\r\n23\r\n24\r\n25\r\n26\r\n27\r\n28\r\n29\r\n30\r\n31\r\n32\r\n33\r\n34\r\n35\r\n36\r\n37\r\n38\r\n39\r\n40\r\n" +
                        "41\r\n42\r\n43\r\n44\r\n45\r\n46\r\n47\r\n48\r\n49\r\n50\r\n51\r\n52\r\n53\r\n54\r\n55\r\n56\r\n57\r\n58\r\n59\r\n60\r\n" +
                        "61\r\n62\r\n63\r\n64\r\n65\r\n66\r\n67\r\n68\r\n69\r\n70\r\n71\r\n72\r\n73\r\n74\r\n75\r\n76\r\n77\r\n78\r\n79\r\n80\r\n" +
                        "81\r\n82\r\n83\r\n84\r\n85\r\n86\r\n87\r\n88\r\n89\r\n90\r\n91\r\n92\r\n93\r\n94\r\n95\r\n96\r\n97\r\n98\r\n99\r\n100\r\n";
                        /* Continue to 1000 */

Console.WriteLine(oneToThousand);
```

Comment: But it´s still a Loop - although you dont write it. And more bad: In IL there maybe Jumps (basically goto´s) ....

Comment: @nabuchodonossor I never said there is no loop. What you're saying is actually what I'm trying to say in this answer.

Comment: I still do not understand, what the teacher tries to tell the kids. I think, his "teachings" lead to developers thinking "Loops are bad" or "Arrays are bad". I´m not happy with it. And before you ask: I personally heard this from "top" developers ...

Comment: @nabuchodonossor Loops are not bad. But there are bad usage of loops (Mostly nested ones). Most people abuse looping when using fancy linq features like `let` introducing nested loops without even noticing. So, loops are not pure evil but they can be abused like any other concept and that leads to slow programs.

Comment: One other way could be the call of an Oracle stored procedure, inside the procedure make a very very tricky query to get the values from 1 to 1000 (or use Parameters), then compose a string in the sp and return this value. You could be the PL/SQL hero ... But of coures: In the sp still an Loop will be used.

Comment: fully agree with "everything" can be abused

Comment: @nabuchodonossor Well if that's a puzzle. You can create a single hard-coded string separated by `\n` and print that in a single go.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive function (DEF) is a function which either calls itself or is in a potential cycle of function calls. As the definition specifies, there are two types of recursive functions. Consider a function which calls itself: we call this type of recursion immediate recursion.

**Example:**

```
public static void PrintTo(int number)
{
    if (number == 0)
        return;

    Console.WriteLine(number);
    PrintTo(number - 1);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    PrintTo(1000);
}
```